# "Multiple dex files" when building PhoneGap app

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, phonegap-build

I'm using [build.phonegap.com](http://build.phonegap.com) to build my app (for Android in this case). However, I get the following error:

```
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/annotation/AnimRes;
```

My understanding is that this is caused by two or more plugins using different Android Support Library versions.

A few solutions I've come across [here](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/Cordova-Ionic-PhoneGap-Deferred-Deep-Linking-SDK/blob/master/README.md#android-resolving-issue-with-multiple-support-lib-v4) is to:

- Adding `multiDexEnabled true` inside defaultConfig tag in `build.gradle`
- Removing the `android-support-v4.jar` in Android `libs` directory.
- Executing `./gradlew clean` in the Android directory
- Excluding `android-support-v4` file for compiling

But, I'm not sure how to access and modify my `build.gradle` file as it's handled by [build.phonegap.com](http://build.phonegap.com).

Any advice would be appreciated.